# How to derive the order of a Runge-Kutta method from its Butcher tableau?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I have a Runge-Kutta method given by the Butcher tableau:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
0 & & & \\
1/2 & 1/2 & & \\
1/3 & 0 & 1/3 & \\\hline
& -1/3& 1/3 &1
\end{array}
$$
I would like to prove that hasn't order $3$. However, I don't know how to attack the problem, so I appreciate any hint or solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you allowed to use order conditions for RK methods? I.e. $\sum_i b_i = 1$ for the first order, $\sum_i b_i c_i = \frac{1}{2}$ for the second order and a pair of $\sum_i b_i c_i^2 = \frac{1}{3}, \sum_{i,j} b_i a_{ij} c_j = \frac{1}{6}$ for the third order.

Comment: I shouldn't use the conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any Runge-Kutta method can be used as a quadrature formula. Just apply it to
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x)
$$
so
$$
y_{n+1} = y_{n} + h \sum b_i f(c_i).
$$
Let's assume that the method is of third order. Thus evaluating 
$y_{n+1} - y_n$ as $$y_{n+1} - y_n = \int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}} f(x) dx \approx h \sum b_i f(c_i)$$ shoud have an error of $O(h^4)$ magnitude (local error of RK method of third order).
Consider $f(x) = x^2$.
$$
\int_0^h x^2 dx = \frac{h^3}{3}\\
h\sum_i b_i c_i^2 = \frac{h}{3}\frac{h^2}{4} + h\frac{h^2}{9} = \frac{7}{36}h^3
$$
which is $O(h^3)$ far from the right answer, so no third order.